# accessing COM Dll from VC ++ Win32 Windows form in VS2008

Tags: visual-c++, dll, com

I was trying to use a COM DLL written VC++ in VB 6 with the help of this Article - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8745/A-Beginner-tutorial-for-writing-simple-COM-ATL-DLL

I have created the COM Dll as well as VB forms and the project works fine.
Now I am trying to use the same COM dll in a Win32 Windows forms application written in VS2008.
I have created a similar form to that of vb, I have added the reference of COM Dll to the project.

I would like to know how to use the same Get and Put functions in VC++.
Any pointers towards related tutorials or any info on how to do it would be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not using C++ when you created a Winforms project, the language extension is C++/CLI.  It is just as easy as in a VB.NET project, simply add a reference to your COM dll.  If this is a regular native project (Win32 > Win32 Project template) then you'll have to learn how to use the #import directive.

Comment: Thanks will try that..